# How to Pythonically test whether a function is called with a certain argument in Python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I've got a Django codebase which contains an endpoint. The endpoint does many things, and I now want to check whether the endpoint calls the function `do_metadata_request` (pasted below) with a specific token.

```
def do_metadata_request(url_info, token):
    metadata_url = f"{settings.META_SERVER_BASE_URL}/{url_info['dossier']}"

    headers = {}
    if token:
        headers['Authorization'] = token

    return requests.get(metadata_url, headers=headers)
```

So after some fiddling around I made the setup below. It works, but it does the actual test in a mocked function which I define outside the test itself. It just doesn't feel elegant or Pythonic at all. I'd rather do the assert inside the test, or at least define the mock_do_metadata_request within the test.

How can I do this more elegantly?

```
class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, status_code, json_content=None, content=None, headers=None):
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.json_content = json_content
        self.content = content
        self.headers = headers

    def json(self):
        return self.json_content

MOCK_TOKEN = "Bearer " + create_test_token([settings.EXTENDED_SCOPE])

def mock_do_metadata_request(url_info, token):
    assert token == MOCK_TOKEN
    return MockResponse(
        200,
        json_content={
            'access': settings.ACCESS_RESTRICTED,
            'documents': [{'barcode': '123', 'access': settings.ACCESS_RESTRICTED}]
        }
    )


class TestFileRetrieval(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()

    @patch('project.metadata.do_metadata_request', side_effect=mock_do_metadata_request)
    def test_token_is_passed_on_to_metadata_server(self, mock_do_metadata_request):
        header = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': MOCK_TOKEN}
        response = self.c.get(IMG_URL, **header)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various `assert_called`, `asset_called_with`, etc. methods of the `Mock` object to assert the arguments the mock was called with or you can use `call_args` or `call_args_list` to get the arguments the mock was called with. If you don't care what value a particular argument had in a call you can use [unittest.mock.ANY](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any) in its place. You can refer these and other methods / attributes of the `Mock` class from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock). An implementation that can work for you can be written as follows:

```py
from unittest.mock import ANY


class TestFileRetrieval(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()

    @patch('project.metadata.do_metadata_request')
    def test_token_is_passed_on_to_metadata_server(self, mock_do_metadata_request):
        mock_do_metadata_request.return_value = MockResponse(
            200,
            json_content={
                'access': settings.ACCESS_RESTRICTED,
                'documents': [{'barcode': '123', 'access': settings.ACCESS_RESTRICTED}]
            }
        )
        header = {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': MOCK_TOKEN}
        response = self.c.get(IMG_URL, **header)
        mock_do_metadata_request.assert_called_with(ANY, MOCK_TOKEN)
```